# Is it possible to dissable TRIM on selected partition?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, hard-drive-recovery, trim, dualboot

I want to install dualboot Win10+Ubuntu on same 2TB SSD.

My idea is to leave each OS 250GB and remaining 1.5TB will be left for media, which both OS will have access to.

I want to make the 1.5TB partition as secure as possible, I mean for example disable TRIM but maybe there is also something else I can to, to be able to recover data, in case SSD will crash ?

Thank you

Comment: TRIM is just to identify which blocks of data are no longer considered in use and can be wiped internally.  There is no reason to disable it and it should not be disabled on an SSD.

Comment: Keep proper backups.

Comment: back-up-ing 1.5T is not fun. There must be a way

Comment: Why do you believe disabling TRIM will have an effect on security?  Can you explain what you mean exactly?  Why can’t you backup the data normally?  How would disabling TRIM decrease the time it takes to backup your data?

Comment: Disabling TRIM will cause your SSD to become very slow. Definitely should not do that. Also, TRIM is a hardware function, not an OS function. The OS does call TRIM, but the hardware executes it.

Comment: my aim is simply make SSD more secure for keeping my data. Backup is obvious, but if there is any other way, how to keep SSD more secure I would go for it. I don't mind to have "storage" partition slow. That's why I want to have OS on different one

Comment: but disabling TRIM does not alter anything related to security. Its only to reallocate free sectores as usable.

Comment: You still have not explained the reason disabling TRIM would increase the “security” of your files.  TRIM doesn’t have an effect on if a file is retained or lost.  It certainly wouldn’t increase the amount of time it takes to backup data.  You do plan on backing up your data?

Comment: You can't disable trim on one partition, nor on an SSD can you do anything to *one* partition. SSDs don't treat partitions like HDs do. they are not contiguous stripes of separated data, an SSD writes to literally anywhere on the drive. This is entirely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) based on a misinterpretation of both partitioning & the "safety" of disabling trim. Your solution, as with any data, is to back it up; frequently & in more than one place.